# Returning variables from search to use in select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I am trying to do a select statement to and use one of the returned variables for another select statement which will be returned.

The query searches based on the field_id = 413.

[image]

I need 6 returned so that it can be used in a query to get all 6 of the rows that have that item_id.

Here is what I have:

```
DECLARE @Results TABLE(result sysname);
INSERT @Results(result);
DECLARE @SQL4 NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Select DISTINCT ITEM_ID, ATRR_VAL from [dbo].[CONTRACT_ATTR] WHERE [ATTR_VAL] LIKE ''%@VALUE%'' AND FIELD_ID = 413 ORDER BY [ATTR_VAL]';
SET @SQL4 = replace(@SQL4, '@VALUE', '123456');
EXEC SP_executesql @SQL4;
SELECT * FR0M @Results
```

I am getting multiple errors even though this attempts to follow an online tutorial. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

EDIT: I'm getting closer:

```
declare @myTable table
(
    ITEM_ID nvarchar(256),
    ATTR_VAL nvarchar(256)
)

insert into @myTable
    exec (N'Select ITEM_ID, ATTR_VAL from [dbo].[CONTRACT_ATTR] WHERE [ATTR_VAL] LIKE ''%123%'' AND FIELD_ID = 413 ORDER BY [ATTR_VAL]') --dynamic query

select * from @myTable
```

Comment: The `INSERT` statement is incomplete. What data are you trying to insert into the table variable?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I am trying to insert (ITEM_ID, ATRR_VAL).

Comment: You can't do that. `@Results` table has only one column. And BTW why use `sysname` instead of `nvarchar`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like this?

Select all rows for an `item` that has an `attr_val` like `@value` for `field_id` 413:

```
select ca.*
  from dbo.contract_attr as ca
  where exists (
    select 1
    from dbo.contract_attr as i
    where i.field_id = 413
      and i.attr_val like  '%'+@value+'%'
      and i.item_id = ca.item_id
    )
```

Just in case you are not aware:

Search criteria with a leading wildcard will cause an index scan instead of an index seek (which is almost always slower, unless they are doing equivalent work). This is called a non-SARGable. SARGable is short for Search ARGument Able.

If you can change to using `like @value+'%'`, it becomes SARGable, and it can take advantage of an index that exists on that column to perform an index seek.

- [SARGable functions in SQL Server - Rob Farley](http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2010/01/22/sargable-functions-in-sql-server/)

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with the code posted:

- `INSERT` statement should be included in the dynamic sql part.
- You cannot use a table variable within the scope of a dynamic sql statement.
- `@Results` table is any way not big enough to hold the data you are trying to insert.

You can use a temp table instead. Try the following piece of code:

```
CREATE TABLE #Results TABLE(ID int, result nvarchar(128) NOT NULL);

DECLARE @SQL4 NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'INSERT INTO #Results(ID, result) 
                               Select DISTINCT ITEM_ID, ATRR_VAL 
                               from [dbo].[CONTRACT_ATTR] 
                               WHERE [ATTR_VAL] LIKE ''%@VALUE%'' AND 
                                     FIELD_ID = 413';
SET @SQL4 = replace(@SQL4, '@VALUE', '123456');
EXEC SP_executesql @SQL4;
SELECT * FR0M #Results ORDER BY [result];
```